# jQuery file extension validation on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have this jQuery code that is used for direct uploading files from client browser to Cloudinary and I want to do a quick check and error return on client side if a file extension is not jpg/jpeg and png.

By default Cloudinary accept almost all file formats, so I already did limit the extension on Cloudinary (server side), so the files don't get saved as soon as they are uploaded. The upload process begins as soon as the file is selected or dropped.

The problem is that the file is first uploaded (the uploading... text is shown) and then it gets rejected by cloudinary. I want the error message to pop up as soon as the not allowed file extension is clicked or dropped to a browser and to prevent the beginning of upload process.

The code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.cloudinary-fileupload')
    .fileupload({ 
      dropZone: '#direct_upload',
      start: function () {
        $('.status_value').text('Starting logo upload...');
      },
      progress: function (e, data) {
        $('.status_value').text('Uploading...');
        var com = Math.round((data.loaded * 100.0) / data.total)
        $("#direct_upload .progress .progress-bar").attr("style","width:"+com+"%")
      },
    })
    .on('cloudinarydone', function (e, data) {
        $('.status_value').text('Uploaded!');
        $("#direct_upload .progress").attr("style","display:none");
        $("#direct_upload .progress .progress-bar").attr("style","width: 0%")

        var info = $('<div class="uploaded_info"/>');

        $(info).append($('<div class="data"/>').append(prettydump(data.result.path)));

          })
        ));
        $('.uploaded_info_holder').append(info);
    });
```

I tried to use this code but had no luck with it as it shows alert message every time I refresh a page:

```
var ext = $('#my_file_field').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {
alert('invalid extension!');
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need acceptFileTypes option:

```
acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
```

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

Bind the event to show an alert (jquery.fileupload-validate.js is necessary):

```
$('.cloudinary-fileupload').bind('fileuploadprocessfail', function (e, data) {
   alert(data.files[data.index].error);    
});
```